# Publishing CSS Styles to Geoserver in Java

Tags: geoserver-rest-api, css, style-manager

I want to directly upload and publish a CSS format style in Java, but after trying for a while, it has failed.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://docs.geoserver.org/2.23.x/en/user/styling/css/tutorial.html

Comment: It sounds like you have made but not presented a code attempt. For coding questions a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck should be included.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could. In order to achieve that you will need to install the CSS Extension for Geoserver from [here](https://docs.geoserver.org/2.23.x/en/user/styling/css/install.html#css-install).

There is also  good tutorial you could check out on how to achieve that from the following link: https://docs.geoserver.org/2.23.x/en/user/styling/css/tutorial.html

In my opinion it is easier to style the data in QGIS then use the GeoCAT plugin to transfer the data styled to Geoserver. You may have your own reasons to wanting to use CSS though.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have found this tutorial and due to its increasing usage, I want to integrate it with Java. However, I have seen that GeoServerRESTStyleManager can only publish SLD files or text in SLD format. I would like to directly publish CSS styles. What should I do

Comment: Or guide me on how to convert CSS format styles to SLD format through Java code, but I couldn't find them in geotools